# React native - Codemagic ios build failed to publish

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa, apple-developer, codemagic

Expected : I need to upload an ipa to app store in flightmode.

Facing :
Below is the response in `build ios` section(coademagic.yaml response) -

```
Successfully created archive at build/ios/xcarchive/Projname_6don6ptw.xcarchive
Export build/ios/xcarchive/Projname_6don6ptw.xcarchive to build/ios/ipa
Execute "xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/ios/xcarchive/Projname_6don6ptw.xcarchive -exportPath build/ios/ipa -exportOptionsPlist /Users/builder/export_options.plist COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO"

▸ Export Succeeded
Successfully exported ipa to build/ios/ipa/Projname.ipa
Raw xcodebuild logs stored in /tmp/xcodebuild_logs/Projname_4fqjb9bq.log
```

And in `publishing` block of(codemagic.yaml):

```
== Gathering artifacts ==

== Publishing artifacts ==

Publishing artifact AppReactNative_40_artifacts.zip
Skip publishing to App Store Connect: no IPAs found
```

Project ipa is created, but I don't understand why it's missing in artifact.zip file.

Answer (score 1):

do you have the next lines in your codemagic.yaml file?

```
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
```

you can find a full example here
https://docs.codemagic.io/getting-started/building-a-react-native-app/#ios-workflow-example

Comment: along with this, I had to run build command from the root of project and not inside ios folder. That's all. :)